# How to filter rows inside a csv file based on their date?

Tags: python, list, csv, datetime, glob

I have a file named `aa_20200907.txt` and it looks like this:

```
#DATA:DD,CARS_INTERNATIONAL:VERSION01.1
2020-09-07T00:00:00.285+02:00,New-York,XX,Audi
2020-09-07T00:01:00.385+02:00,London,100,Mercedes
2020-09-07T00:02:00.255+02:00,New-York,90,Ford
2020-09-07T00:03:00.523+02:00,New-York,91,BMW
2020-09-08T00:00:58.444+02:00,New-York,12,BMW
2020-09-08T00:01:55.336+02:00,New-York,11,Mercedes
```

I have a code which is filtering the rows based on 2 conditions.

1. `Condition_1:` I only want the rows where `index[2]` is a digit.
2. `Condition_2`: I only want the rows if `index[1]` (the date) is the same as the date mentioned in the processed filename. The date of the filenames is asigned to a list named `missing_dates`.

Now below code works perfectly on `condition_1`, the problem is that `condition_2` is not working the way I want it to work. Please note that I normally run this code on multiple files which means `missing_dates` cotains more values.

**This is my code:**

```
import csv
import datetime 
from pathlib import Path

root=Path(r'c:\data\PPE\Desktop\test_folder')

def filter_row(r, date):  
    condition_1 = r[2].isdigit()  #<-- select only the rows if index 2 is numbers. 
    condition_2 = date != missing_date #<-- select only the rows of that specific day.
    
    return condition_1 and condition_2

missing_dates = ['20200907']

output_list = []
for missing_date in missing_dates:
    # print(f"processing {missing_date}")
    files=[fn for fn in (e for e in root.glob(f"**/*_{missing_date}.txt") if e.is_file())]
    for file in files:      
        with open(file, 'r') as log_file:
            reader = csv.reader(log_file, delimiter = ',')
            next(reader) # skip header
            for row in reader:
                if filter_row(row, missing_date):
                    output_list.append(row)
                    
print(output_list)
```

**This is my current output:**

```
[]
```

**This is the desired output:**

```
['2020-09-07T00:01:00.385+02:00', 'London', '100', 'Mercedes']
['2020-09-07T00:02:00.255+02:00', 'New-York', '90', 'Ford']
['2020-09-07T00:03:00.523+02:00', 'New-York', '91', 'BMW']
```

*Please note that I do not want to write a whole new code. I just want to fix `condition_2` and keep the current code as I feel comfortable with it.

Comment: Any good reason for not using pandas? Pandas make such tasks much simpler.

Comment: @quest this piece of code is part of a much bigger script. Will cost to much time to rewrite everything to pandas.

Comment: You are doing this `if filter_row(row,'20200907')` this will always return false as '20200907' will be always equal to itself 20200907. Your condition_2 does not makes sense.

Comment: @ChandanMalla Thats why I try to refix my condition_2 but I dont know how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go buddy:

Input:

```
#DATA:DD,CARS_INTERNATIONAL:VERSION01.1
2020-09-07T00:00:00.285+02:00,New-York,XX,Audi
2020-09-07T00:01:00.385+02:00,London,100,Mercedes
2020-09-07T00:02:00.255+02:00,New-York,90,Ford
2020-09-07T00:03:00.523+02:00,New-York,91,BMW
2020-09-08T00:00:58.444+02:00,New-York,12,BMW
2020-09-08T00:01:55.336+02:00,New-York,11,Mercedes
```

Code:

```
import csv
import datetime 
from pathlib import Path
import os

os.chdir('/home/chandanmalla/Desktop/')

def filter_row(r, date):  
    condition_1 = r[2].isdigit()  #<-- select only the rows if index 2 is numbers. 
    condition_2 = r[0].split('T')[0] == date #<-- select only the rows of that specific day.
    return condition_1 and condition_2

missing_dates = ['2020-09-07']
file_end_name = ['20200907']

output_list = []


files=[]
for f in os.listdir():
    for m_d in file_end_name:
        if f.endswith(m_d +'.txt'):
            files.append(f)
for file,m_d in zip(files,missing_dates):
    with open(file, 'r') as log_file:
        reader = csv.reader(log_file, delimiter = ',')
        next(reader) # skip header
        for row in reader:
            if filter_row(row, m_d):
                output_list.append(row)
                
print(output_list)
```

Output

```
[['2020-09-07T00:01:00.385+02:00', 'London', '100', 'Mercedes'],
 ['2020-09-07T00:02:00.255+02:00', 'New-York', '90', 'Ford'],
 ['2020-09-07T00:03:00.523+02:00', 'New-York', '91', 'BMW']]
```

Your code had a problem with condition_2 and also with below line of code, zero files were there when ran below piece of code.

```
    files=[fn for fn in (e for e in root.glob(f"**/*_{missing_date}.txt") if e.is_file())]
```

Comment: You can change '20200907' to '2020-09-07' by using code.

Comment: Also, if the last line of your file has record with date 2020-09-07, it will also add some garbage characters, make sure to fix it.

Comment: Thank you, but you have changed the second part of my code to much. Why is that?

Comment: ` files=[fn for fn in (e for e in root.glob(f"**/*_{missing_date}.txt") if e.is_file())] `  This was producing empty results, so I instead used a different solution to get files from the directory

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach

**Ex:**

```
import os
import re
import csv
import datetime

with open(filePath) as infile:
    filename = os.path.basename(filePath)
    print(filename)  # -> aa_20200907.txt
    dateToCheck = datetime.datetime.strptime(re.sub(r"[^\d]", "", filename), "%Y%m%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  # Get Date
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for line in reader:
        if line[0].startswith(dateToCheck) and  line[2].isdigit(): # Conditions
            print(line)
```

**Output:**

```
['2020-09-07T00:01:00.385+02:00', 'London', '100', 'Mercedes']
['2020-09-07T00:02:00.255+02:00', 'New-York', '90', 'Ford']
['2020-09-07T00:03:00.523+02:00', 'New-York', '91', 'BMW']
```

Comment: Thank you but I dont want to rewrite a whole new code. I want to keep the same script I have right now. I just want to fix `condition_2` in `filter_row`

Comment: @TangerCity..You do not need to rewrite the whole code. replace `if filter_row(row, missing_date)` with `if row[0].startswith(dateToCheck) and  row[2].isdigit():`

Comment: I want to keep the function `filter_row`. I just want to adjust `condition_2`